# ngrx: pushed data from socket

Tags: ngrx

As I am evaluating and learning `ngrx`, I wondering about a use case where a socket feeds data every second.

I have a large app that receives socket data every second. From what I understand this data should live in the state tree. Wouldn't I end up with thousands of state history objects and degrade performance and memory?  Or am I not understanding something...thank-you

EDIT:
The data coming in is a collection which should replace the previous collection and is shared in various views.

Comment: well, it depends on what your data is and how is it used. in general, there is no difference between keeping it in state or in a variable as thats pretty much all state is: big (selectable) variable. but, if your data is changing every second then you could rethink even a need for the state. who will use that data? one component or several? you need to provide a few more details about the usecase.

Comment: In production, according to your settings ngrx won't keep track of previous state. Just the last one. If you use the debug tool, you can set how many history objects you want maximum

Comment: Thanks for the replies, I updated my question with a bit more information. @Maxime, so if I understand you correctly ngrx will destroy my previous state objects?

Comment: Umh not really NGRX. Because you might still want at some point to keep some part of your state. What NGRX does is just NOT keeping a reference to a previous state which allows the browser to run the garbage collector on it at some point and release unused memory. But of course if you do keep a reference on some part of your state, the gabage collector won't delete it.

If you use time travelling with debug tool, you can explicitly define how many state you want to keep but yes by default and without the debug tool, NGRX won't save previous states.